# How do I display http request data, with data from another http request as param?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, typescript

hi I'm trying to output multiple bootstrap 3 panels with a heading and list items with angular2 getting data from a web api

functions in my service.ts:

with the following function I get a json containing the panel headings which are components i will use

```
getComponents(type: string): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:14373/api/devices/components/' + type)
       .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

And with this function I get a json containing all values which will be the list items

```
getComponentValues(type: string, component: string): Observable<string[]> {
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:14373/api/devices/components/' + type + '/' + component)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

in my component.ts I save the values of components (headings) in a string array with this function

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.route.params
            .subscribe(
                (params: any) => {
                    this.currentType = params['type'];
                    this.deviceService.getComponents(this.currentType).subscribe(
                        (data: string[]) => {
                            this.components = data;
                        }
                    );
                }
            );

    }
```

then I tried to write a function which will return the componentValues (list-items) as array and output them with a nested *ngFor loop.

```
 getComponentValues(type: string, component: string) {

        this.deviceService.getComponentValues(type, component)
            .subscribe(
                (data: string[]) => {
                    return data;
                }
            )
    }
```

template:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let component of components">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">{{component}}</div>
    <!-- List group -->
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let val of getComponentValues(currentType, component)">
            {{val}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

but this doesn't seem to work and since I've never even touched angular2 or angular before I don't know if I'm on the right track or which approach would actually be best practice.. also I obviously don't understand observables yet

Answer (score 1):

You could just return a observable from `getComponentValues` method which will be called for each component. And use that for inner `ngFor` with  `async` pipe.

**Markup**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let component of components">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">{{component}}</div>
    <!-- List group -->
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let val of getComponentValues(currentType, component) | async">
            {{val}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
this.subscription = this.route.params
  .subscribe(
  (params: any) => {
    this.currentType = params['type'];
    this.deviceService.getComponents(this.currentType).subscribe(
      (data: string[]) => {
        this.components = data;
      }
    );
  }
);

getComponentValues(type: string, component: string) {
  return this.deviceService.getComponentValues(type, component);
}
```

Comment: thank for your quick answer, but do I have to do something else... cuz with your modifications. I get this error: Property 'componentValues' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: @jcal I thought component is object, give me a minute, let me edit my answer

Comment: I just tried to change the datatype to any[] which makes the error msg go away.. but nothing is outputted :(

Comment: @jcal tell me one thing, component is string/object?

Comment: its just a string

Comment: unfortunately the data of `getComponentValues()` is not displayed :/  in the template (I only see the headings)... but still thanks for your effort

Comment: @jcal have you updated your html with what I updated in answer? You have to use async pipe over it

Comment: @jcal atleast component are getting displayed?

Comment: yes the headings are displayed, but the list items are not.. they aren't even generated.. its like, the observable returns null

Comment: @jcal As I can say `getComponentValues` method is returning a observable, it should work

Comment: okay .. still thank you.. I just tried to console.log() in my service function if my url is right and there's an endless loop is that normal?

Comment: is this approach actually viable and should I try to find the reason why it's not working.. or do you think I should research for another approach? @Pankaj Parkar

Comment: Its correct approach, not bad one, though you can improve it. Can you please check `getComponentValues` is returning a data correctly?